# Type-hint different number of return values with python mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm wondering how to type-hint something sucha s the following:

```py
from typing import Any, Union, Dict, Tuple

# here x is 
def f(x : str) -> Union[Tuple[int, bool], Tuple[int, str, float]]:
    if 'something' in x:
        return 1, 'this', 3.0
    return 1, True


a,b = f(x = 'this is something')
x,y,z = f(x = 'this is')
```

This raises the error:

```
main.py:9: error: Too many values to unpack (2 expected, 3 provided)
main.py:10: error: Need more than 2 values to unpack (3 expected)
```

So the problem is fairly clear - i have a method which can return two different sets of values, but the expected solution (`Union`) doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: The best way to do this is probably just to return `None` for the third value when `x` is `False`. Then you unpack it with `a, b, _ = ...`. Or if you ever need to ignore multiple values, you can use `a, b, *_ = ...`.

Comment: @Lecdi I considered that - but I still don't know how to handle this scenario, and potentially I might not be able to refactor code to use `a, b, *_` etc in order to use that approach, so I'd be interested to know how to type it. Thanks though :)

Comment: The problem isn't so much the return-type hint (which is accurate) as the attempt to unpack at *runtime* the wrong value. The compiler has to *statically* produce code for the unpacking that requires *dynamic* information (about the size of the tuple returned). That is, just because you know that the function can return one or the other doesn't mean you can make use of that information in the way you want.

Comment: When receiving a value of type `Union[x, y]`, it's not enough to know that the type is either `x` or `y`; you have to be prepared to *use* a value of either type. `a, b = ... ` is not prepared to use a value of type `Tuple[int, int, int]`, and `x, y, z = ...` is not prepared to use a value of type `Tuple[int, int]`.

Comment: Basically, the difficulty in typing this reveals that you have not written (statically) type-safe code, so the solution is to fix the code, not the type hint.

Comment: In general, a method that could return values of two different types should probably be two different methods.

Comment: @chepner thanks - so in the case of `x='this is something'` in the example, mypy does *not* return `Tuple[int,str,float]`, but it's still a Union of the two return types. For some reason I thought that mypy would narrow it down to the "correct" return type in this case - just that there could be more than one.

Comment: No, because `a, b = f('this is something')` is simply *wrong*; it will break at runtime. You wouldn't *want* that to be accepted, even if `a, b = f('hi there')` will not break.

Comment: The type checker cannot (or at least does not) consider the value of the argument to `f` (because this is only a special case where it's "obvious" that the condition will hold). Would you expect `a, b = f(input())` to be considered safe?

Comment: @chepner to be type-safe would `f(input())` need to be able to ensure that the value of `input()` passed to `f` was a string ? In which case - no, I would have to catch that within `f` using `isinstance` or something I expect (and if I'm doing that - perhaps it's _not_ type-safe?)

Answer (score 0):

If the function is always returning a tuple of `int`s, you can try this solution:

```py
def f() -> tuple[int, ...]:
```

The `tuple[int, ...]` type is saying that this function is going to return a `tuple` containing integers only.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense but isn't the case unfortunately, I will update the example to make this clearer, sorry about that.

Comment: This would just trade one problem for another anyway. It would make `a, b, c, d = f()` acceptable, even though `f` never returns a value that can be unpacked into 4 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the error messages: you are using mypy. This static type checker cannot by itself determine the return type based on the function's arguments. You have to help it.

Imports:

```
from typing import Tuple, cast, overload, Literal
```

Solutions:

### Assert

```
f_return = f(x='this is something')
assert len(f_return) == 2, 'Iterable of length 2 expected.'
a, b = f_return
```

```
f_return = f(x='this is')
assert len(f_return) == 3, 'Iterable of length 3 expected.'
x, y, z = f_return
```

The assert checks the tuple's length at run time and throws Assertion Error when it is different. It also narrows the type for mypy.

### Cast

```
a, b = cast(Tuple[int, bool], f(x='this is something'))
```

```
x, y, z = cast(Tuple[int, str, float], f(x='this is'))
```

Cast does not alter the run time behaviour. The assignment statement will fail when the number of the tuple elements will not match the left side.

### Overload

For arguments distinguishable by typing:

```
@overload
def f(x: Literal['this is something']) -> Tuple[int, str, float]:
    ...

@overload
def f(x: Literal['this is']) -> Tuple[int, bool]:
    ...
    
def f(x: str) -> Tuple:
    if x == 'this is something':
        return 1, 'this', 3.0
    elif x == 'this is':
        return 1, True
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Unexpected value {x = }')

a, b = f('this is')
x, y, z = f('this is something')
```

In this case the caller does not need to do the type narrowing or overriding.

### Summary

You can see that the idea of returning a union of types complicates things. It is best to design the function's interface to avoid it.

Comment: It would be really useful if you express what you do not like about this answer.